# Restcomm android sdk with other sip servers

Tags: android, sip, voip, restcomm

I am trying to build an Android VOIP client application for a [voip server](http://bestdialing.com) and planning to use [Restcomm android sdk](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/sdks/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start.html#android-sdk-guide). But according to their getting started guide they specify **Restcomm Communications Platform** as a  prerequisite . So I am confused whether it works for the kind of SIP/VOIP server I am trying to make the app for. Does anyone have any idea about it? I tried to mail them but they redirected me to SO. So it would be great if someone who have used this SDK suggest me.

Comment: How you setup the SDK? Says the ip, username etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Restcomm Android SDK is build on top of JAIN SIP, which means that in its core it is a SIP client, so it should be able to talk to any SIP server. The only thing you need to keep in mind is that it uses webrtc for media, in order to better traverse NAT and generally take advantage of all the goodies webrtc has to offer.

Please let me know if you have any further questions

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis

Comment: does it mean that I can use it directly for any SIP servers, I mean without modifying any lower level APIs and codes?

Comment: Right, you should be able to do that for any SIP server, as long as you remember the media part that I described above.

Comment: Please note that for the Media Part, if your VoIP Server doesn't support WebRTC standards, you could potentially use Restcomm-Connect as a WebRTC gateway connect to your VoIP Server without any issues